# Macros/Shapeless to control string value in method

Tags: scala, shapeless, scala-macros

I'm creating a DSL where users have a given when then, where they pass a string with the action they want.

All those actions are controlled using some regular expressions. 
Now using shapeless or macros I would like to control what users compones using the DSL, and in case the string does not fit the string as we expect make the code don't compile.

Si for instance

```
Given("a good action") -> fine
When("wrong string action") -> compilation error
```

Can anybody please point me to a good blog or documentation of how to achieve this?

Regards

After the solution of Gabriele now I´m facing a design issue. This is my vaidator class

```
object DSLValidator {

  import scala.language.experimental.macros

  def Given(message: String): Any = macro checkActionImpl

  def When(message: String): Any = macro checkActionImpl

  def Then(message: String): Any = macro checkActionImpl

  def And(message: String): Any = macro checkActionImpl

  def checkActionImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(message: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    def isValidAction(s: String): Boolean = checkMessage(s)

    message match {
      case _tree@Literal(Constant(s: String)) if isValidAction(s) => _tree
      case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Invalid action for DSL. Check the allowed actions in RegexActions")
    }
  }

  val PARAMS = "(.*)=(.*)"
  val PAYLOAD_VALUE_REGEX = s"^Payload $PARAMS".r

  def checkMessage(action: String): Boolean = {
    action match {
      case PAYLOAD_VALUE_REGEX(c, c1) => true
      case "Make a request to server" => true
      case _ => false
    }
  }
}
```

And if I invoke the Given/When/Then from another class with wrong arguments the compiler complain as we expect.

```
  @Test
  def TestDSL(): Unit = {
    DSLValidator.Given("Make a request to wrong")--> not compiling
    DSLValidator.When("Payload code=works") --> compiling
    println("End")
  }
```

But now thinking the whole idea of was not only to check the values on compilation time but also execute the logic of the Given/When/then

And I realize than when I use macros in a function there´s nothing else that we can do so.

```
   def Given(message: String): Any =  { 
          macro checkActionImpl
          //My bussiness logic
      }
```

is not compiling, so my question is, where can I put now the business logic and where the invocation of the macro function to continue working.

Also using a static class as bridge does not work and wont compile since the string message does not fit.

```
object Macros {

  def Given(message: String) = {
    DSLValidator.Given(message)
    //Logic here
    println("Given")
  }
}

Macros.Given("Make a request to wrong")
```

Any idea?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think shapeless cannot help you in this case, so a macro would be the way to go.

Here's a skeleton for a macro you can start from:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
def Given(message: String): /* the return type of Given */ = macro givenImpl

def givenImpl(c: Context)(message: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  def isValid(s: String): Boolean = ??? // your validation logic here

  message match {
    case case t @ Literal(Constant(s: String)) if isValid(s) => t
    case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Invalid message")
  }

}
```

In order to fully understand this I can recommend you to read:

- http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html
- https://blog.scalac.io/2016/02/25/def-hello-macro-world.html

Comment: Thanks for the blogs, I think I quite understand the concept of the white/black context, and the Tree still a little bit tricky. I think I understood your example, but is not compiling. I had to change message: c.Tree by c.Expr[String] is that correct?

Comment: ah yes, sorry, I literally typed this into the StackOverflow box :)

Comment: actually you can use `c.Tree` and replace `message.tree` with `message`. I think this is the most recent way of doing that (i.e. preferring `Tree` to `Expr`)

Comment: Man, your´re genius! Works like a charm. I feel really bad to get your hole solution and not being able to figure out by myself, but I guess that´s why teacher are there. Thanks for so neat solution about such complex topic.

Comment: No problem, it's a complicated topic. I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: I found a design problem, could you please look the second part of my question and see if you have any idea how normally people design the use of macros and execution of the business logic. Thanks!!

Comment: the macro is just a syntactic rewrite, so you can write the invocation to the original methods. Can you provide an example of the business logic?

Comment: about using a `String` variable, you're out of luck. There's no way you can statically check the string if it's not a literal.

Comment: If you see the in test that I wrote,  Given("Make a request to wrong") this method implementation, just make a request to a service.

Comment: So you say is not possible make it works what you did unless you invoke directly?. Not event using implicits?. Too bad!, it was so cool has this feature in my DSL

Comment: I found a hack that I think is not that bad. Since the marco function return the very same string I´m using a -> method as name and I adding the String in there Given ->("Make a request to server") so I´m calling the -> to validate in compilation time and since it´s returning the String is embebed in the Given invocation.